# Finding a large file being created by the system

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage

I ran some code that caused root file system to run out of space; the code then crashes and the file is deleted. I need to find out which file is being created there.

How can I quickly (while the program is running, i.e., I only have ~30 seconds) find all files in the given file system that are greater than 1 GB and modified or created just now?

(I'm guessing python's sqlite3 uses root file system for something, but obviously without seeing the file I have no way of knowing.)

Comment: Have you considered instead using `lsof` to list all files that the program opens for writing? See for example [lsof: show files open as read-write](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115722/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver just tried. the only open file is in /var/tmp, but it shows as "deleted": `python    24853 max    6u   REG    8,1 3821580012  788060 /var/tmp/etilqs_xARlZag1jj945jH (deleted)`. It's also far bigger than the space on the root filesystem. Still, the root filesystem slowly reduces its free space until it hits 0.

Answer (score 1):

With the following command you can find the recently modified/created file on the system disregarding the file size:

```
find ${1} -type f -size +1G| xargs stat --format '%Y :%y %n' 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2-
```

Comment: It works correctly (in the sense of finding other files), but still doesn't find any files being created while the process is running. Then I just get the message "The volume Filesystem root has only 200 MB disk space remaining", and `df` command really shows `/` is almost full while `/home` has 50 GB free.